# Java : Set time part of java.SQL.Timestamp without changing the date

Tags: java, timestamp

I am working on a Java project in which I have a `Time` object in another column. But for some query purposes, I need the time as a part of Timestamp. For this reason, I decided to call the `setTime` method of java.SQL.Timestamp, but it resets the date to 1970.

**How can I only change the time part in java.SQL.Timestamp?**

COde :

```
            object.getTimestamp().setTime(object.getTTime().getTime());
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more what are you trying to do, maybe post your query, or more code?

Comment: @karelss : Sure. I have two objects one is java.SQL.Timestamp and other is Time. I want to set only the time part in Timestamp while keeping the date in it constant. THe source of the time is Time object.

Comment: You have to work with long representation of the time, and extract the "time" part and add it to your other object, i think

Comment: @karelss : Yes, extract time from Time object, and set time ONLY in TImestamp object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work as with a normal `java.util.Date`, update the time part using `Calendar`, then update the timestamp with

```
  setTime(long time)
```

Example

```
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(time.getTime());
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    ts.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(ts.getTime());
```

**EDIT**

Example 2

```
    Timestamp ts; 
    //give some value to ts
    Time time ;
    //give some value to time

    //Calendar based on ts          
    Calendar cTs=Calendar.getInstance();
    cTs.setTimeInMillis(ts.getTime());

    //Calendar based on time
    Calendar cTime=Calendar.getInstance();
    cTime.setTimeInMillis(time.getTime());

    cTs.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, cTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    cTs.set(Calendar.MINUTE, cTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    cTs.set(Calendar.SECOND, cTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cTs.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cTime.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    //set value of ts based on the modified cTs
    ts.setTime(cTs.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println(ts.getTime());
```

Comment: What do you mean by works as normal with Date? Can you describe what you want to say, I cannot understand.

Comment: see the example in my answer

Comment: And in your above example where are you setting hours and minutes from Time object?

Comment: there's a small error, in second line of my code, now is correct. The Time class extends Date, so you can use getTime and manipulate it with Calendar. And of course you can manipulate also the date part, if you need

Comment: This way if I do, then the the TImestamp is set to current time, not to the one I have defined. So, There is a timestamp object like 04.11.2016 22.00 .. I only want to change the 22.00 part of it from a Time object..

Comment: It is what  my example does, I update the calendar HOUR MINUTE SECOND e MILLISECOND to 00:00:00.00000 see the lines where the calendar is updated (rows 3,4,5,6 of the example)..

Comment: See new example. Anyway you can play with Calendar as much as you need